# errorBuilder callback of Image.network not invoked when in DecorationImage

Tags: flutter

Why does `errorBuilder` of `Image.network` not get invoked when in `DecorationImage`?

Instead error that occurs in `Image.network` invokes `onError` of `DecorationImage`. So I cannot substitute failed image with another widget.

Here is the code with this situation. I took the example from the [documentation for errorBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/errorBuilder.html) and amended it so that `Image.network` is in `DecorationImage`. See below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatelessWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          border: Border.all(),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          image: DecorationImage(
              onError: (obj, st) {
                  print('ONERROR-ONERROR-ONERROR');
              },
              image: Image.network(
                'https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg',
                errorBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                  // Appropriate logging or analytics, e.g.
                  // myAnalytics.recordError(
                  //   'An error occurred loading "https://example.does.not.exist/image.jpg"',
                  //   exception,
                  //   stackTrace,
                  // );
                  return const Text('ERROR');
                },
              ).image
          )
      ),
      child: const SizedBox(height: 200, width: 200),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `image:Image.network().image` that returns `ImageProvider`. It means `image` will get from `Image.network` only when there is no error and image load perfectly.
When the issue happens, you can see `onError` message.

Now for the use case `errorBuilder`  return a widget that can't be directly assign on `image`.

This might be call overengineered to handle the error.

```dart
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final dImage = DecorationImage(
     onError: (obj, st) {
       print('ONERROR-ONERROR-ONERROR');
     },
     image: Image.network(
       'h .exist/image.jpg',
       errorBuilder:
           (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
         debugPrint("onError B");

         return Text("rr");
       },
     ).image,
   );
   return Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Colors.white,
       border: Border.all(),
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
       image: dImage.onError != null
           ? DecorationImage(
               image: NetworkImage(imgUrl), //default image URL on null case
             )
           : dImage,
     ),
     child: const SizedBox(height: 200, width: 200),
   );
 }
```

I will prefer using Container child with stack if I need overlay.

**We already have `child` option and simplify the case.** This is a simple and cleaner approach you can just tell by reading the code, don't have to scroll the mouse.

```dart
return Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
  child: Image.network(
    'h .exist/image.jpg',
    errorBuilder:
        (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
      debugPrint("onError B");
      return Center(child: Text("Error"));
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you a lot. Now I understand why it happens, after you mentioned that `errorBuilder return a widget that can't be directly assign on image`. Accepted your answer. I will use stack, as it more or less fits my needs. Child doesn't fit in my case, unfortunately. It was important for me to understand the nature of why `errorBuilder` wasn't executed.